# Static tables with user filter options to custom views using Javascript / CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Sorry this is long but I have 3 questions related to the same problem. Any advice would be appreciated!

I have a script that converts a CSV file into a static HTML file (or XML file).

For example, this is the HTML file:

```
<div id="r1">
<div id="r1_hardware_name">Hard disk meter</div>
<div id="r1_software_name">Hard_disk_meter</div>
<div id="r1_description">Hard disk meter for temperature</div>
<div id="r1_size">64</div>
<div id="r1_status">Active</div>
<div id="r1_version">5</div>
<div id="r1_value">0x00001<div>
</div>
<div id="r2">
<div id="r2_hardware_name">CPU meter</div>
<div id="r2_software_name">CPU_meter</div>
<div id="r2_description">CPU meter for temperature</div>
<div id="r2_size">32</div>
<div id="r2_status">Active</div>
<div id="r2_version">1</div>
<div id="r2_value">0x00002<div>
</div>
<div id="r3">
<div id="r3_hardware_name">Memory meter</div>
<div id="r3_software_name">Memory_meter</div>
<div id="r3_description">Memory meter for temperature</div>
<div id="r3_size">64</div>
<div id="r3_status">Passive</div>
<div id="r3_version">2</div>
<div id="r3_value">0x00003<div>
</div>
```

On the HTML page, this needs to be displayed in two separate tables. Something like the following. **Is it possible to make these tables based on the html above using CSS?**

```
HW Name           Size    Status
Hard disk meter   64      active
CPU meter         32      active
Memory meter      64      passive

SW Name           Version  Value
Hard_disk_meter   5        0x00001
CPU_meter         1        0x00002
Memory_meter      2        0x00003
```

The page also needs to have links on the name. Such that when the user clicks on the "Hard disk Meter" name on either table, it will display a details table such as:

```
HW Name:     Hard Disk Meter
SW Name:     Hard_disk_meter
Description: Hard disk meter for temperature
Size:        64
Status:      Active
Version:     5
Value:       0x00001
```

I thought this part could be done using some sort of javascripting. **I'm considering using jQuery with a simple toggle hide on rest of document and showing details table attached to another CSS table definition. Would this be the best way?**

The last part is having the html page view filterable. There will be form at the top of the page and the user can select a value range (start / end) and the result would be the same two tables above in that range. Also the user can search for row id (ex. r1, r2, r3) and that would show the details table above. The only example I can find that comes close to this type of functionality is tiddlywiki. http://tiddlywiki.com/

**But is there a simple way, perhaps using jQuery, to do this filtering and search function?**

Answer (score 0):

**HTML Changes**

```
<div id="r1_value">0x00001</div>
```

div tag was not closed in r1,r2,r3

**CSS**

```
#r1,#r2,#r3,.details_r1,.details_r2,.details_r3{
display:none;
margin:20px;
}
.container{
margin:20px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var meterId = ['r1','r2','r3'];
var parameters1 = ['hardware_name','size','status']
var parameters2 = ['software_name','version','value'];
var tableTemplate='<div class="container"><table><tr><td>HW Name</td><td>Size</td><td>Status</td></tr>';

for(i=0;i<meterId.length;i++){
tableTemplate += '<tr>';
for(j=0;j<3;j++){
    var x = '#'+meterId[i]+'_'+parameters1[j];
    if(j==0)
        tableTemplate += '<td><a href="#" onclick=detailsShow("'+meterId[i]+'")>'+$(x).html()+'</a></td>';
    else
        tableTemplate += '<td>'+$(x).html()+'</td>';    
}
tableTemplate += '</tr>';
}
tableTemplate += '</table></div>';
tableTemplate +='<div class="container"><table><tr><td>SW Name</td><td>Version</td><td>Value</td></tr>';
for(i=0;i<meterId.length;i++){
tableTemplate += '<tr>';
for(j=0;j<3;j++){
    var x = '#'+meterId[i]+'_'+parameters2[j];
    tableTemplate += '<td>'+$(x).html()+'</td>';    
}
tableTemplate += '</tr>';
}
tableTemplate += '</table></div>';
$("body").append($(tableTemplate));
var detailsTemplate = '';
for(i=0;i<meterId.length;i++){
detailsTemplate += '<div class="details_'+meterId[i]+'"><table>';
for(j=0;j<3;j++){
    var x = '#'+meterId[i]+'_'+parameters1[j];
    var y = '#'+meterId[i]+'_'+parameters2[j];
    detailsTemplate += '<tr><td>'+parameters1[j]+'</td><td>'+$(x).html()+'</td></tr>';  
    detailsTemplate += '<tr><td>'+parameters2[j]+'</td><td>'+$(y).html()+'</td></tr>';  
}
detailsTemplate += '</table></div>'
 }
 $("body").append($(detailsTemplate));

function detailsShow(x){
$('[class^="details_"]').hide();
$('.details_'+x).show();
}
```